# No exports were found that math the constraint: VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I recently faced this error in VS2013 while trying to open an application:

```
The debugger cannot continue running the process.
The composition produced a single composition error, with 3 root causes.

1) No exports were found that match the constraint:
      ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Javascript.ProjectMetro.Debuggers.JsJmcProjectControl
       RequiredTypeIdentity        Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Project.Metro.Debuggers.JsJmcProjectControl

2) No exports were found that match the constraing:
      ConstractName     Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Project.Metro.IMetroProject
      RequiredTypeIdentity      Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Project.Metro.IMetroProject

3) No exports were found that match the constraint:
      ConstractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Project.ProjectContextHelper
      RequiredTypeIdentity      Mirosoft.VisulaStudio.JavaScript.Project.ProjectContextHelper
```

The other solutions posted suggest to clear the ComponentModelCache. The is no such directory leading to the cache specified in VS2013. I would like to know why this error occurs and how I can fix it.

Comment: did you figure that out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: yea this is because of some package i had upgraded. did you upgrade anything recently? To solve it, i had to uninstall my VS and install a new one and don't upgrade. Let me know if it works.